# 0x6efcc4 output in the txt file

Tags: c++, console-application, fstream, ifstream

I'm a novel student. I have to code a console program which takes a number in input from the user (will be an array in the future but it doesn't matter now), saves it in a txt file and, when you close the program and restart it, it loads the number you previously saved in the txt file into another variable (again, it's going to be an array in the future). Imagine it like a software a librarian would be using to save all the data about the books it has stored. I thought about making two variables, one ifstream and the other ofstream, both referring to the same txt file, so that I can read and write on the same file without needing an external one. I know you can also use fstream with :in and :out (something like this) but I read that you have to reset the point where the program starts reading and i believe it's just too complicated and unnecessary for my program at the moment. So far I tried to input a number and check if it gets saved, but 0x6efcc4 is the only output I get, either I type in "0", "143", "dog"... whatever (the input is a variable string type) and I can't figure out why. I'll post two screens both of the code and the txt file I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int DIN = 2;

int main()
{
    ofstream saving("save.txt");
    ifstream loading("save.txt");
    string input[DIM];

    if (! saving || !loading)
    {
        cout << "One of the files did not open correctly" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cin >> input[1];
        saving << input;
        saving.close();
        loading.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, I noticed I can only post one image or maybe I just don't see the option to post more. The txt file is literally a blank txt file named exactly like in the code with 0x6efcc4 written in it just once in the first line

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. Rather post the code.

Comment: Please post code *as part of the question*. External links grow stale, and images don't allow us to copy & paste the code to check it.

Answer (score 0):

So why do you input to `input[1]` but output `input`? That's the cause of your error, try this instead `saving << input[1];`

What you are seeing in the output file is the address of the `input` array, when what you wanted was the contents of the `input` array.

Also I'd strongly recommend against having the file open for input and output simultaneously. Open it for input when you need to read something, and close it after you've finished. Similarly, open it for output when you want to write something and again close it when you've finished.

Comment: Hey you were right, such a stupid mistake actually :P thanks for help. I will also change the open/close thing now that you made me notice it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on your code again on `cin >> input` statement.

Your code has defined something inputted by the user in array element 2 `[1]`.

If you use the following, you'll get rid of your error:

```
cin >> input[1];
```

But all the text after a space will be omitted. Hence, better use:

```
std::getline(std::cin, input[1]);
```